# all subgroups of $\mathbb Z_2^3$ including $(0,1,1)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I want to write all subgroups of $\mathbb Z_2^3$ including $(0,1,1)$

I guess the only property that must hold is the closure.

So every closed subset including $(0,1,1)$ are the solutions.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True. Since every element of $\Bbb Z_2^3$ is its own inverse, then inverses and identity will actually follow from closure under the group operation, in this case. (At least, for *non-empty* subsets. The empty subset vacuously satisfies closure under the group operation, but is not a subgroup.)

Answer (score 3):

You might consult [GAP 4.6.4](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2013/004130.html) to find these subgroups as well, Mahdi:

```
gap> G:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,2);;
   > H:=DirectProduct( G,G,G);;
gap> S:=AllSubgroups(H);;
gap> Filtered(e,t->(3,4)(5,6) in Elements(S));
```

---

```
Group( [ (3,4)(5,6) ] ), Group( [ (5,6), (3,4) ] ), 
Group( [ (3,4)(5,6), (1,2) ] ), Group( [ (3,4)(5,6), (1,2)(5,6) ] ), 
Group( [ (5,6), (3,4), (1,2) ] )
```

Comment: Nice use of this software +1 ;-)

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to add that GAP constructs the permutation representation of the direct product of three copies of the group generated by the transposition (1,2) as a group generated by transpositions (1,2), (3,4) and (5,6). Tuples (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) are mapped to (1,2), (3,4) and (5,6) respectively.